# Jquery - How to select a row's id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am a newbie with jquery.  I have a table as follows:

```
<td id="dropmenu">
    <?php echo $user->first_name;?>
</td>

<td id="dropmenu" >
    <?php echo $user->last_name; ?>
 </td>

 <td>
    <?php echo $user->email; ?>
 </td>

 <td id="userid">
    <?php echo  $user->userid; ?>
 </td>
```

In my js file, I have the following.  I under #dropdown I add a edit and delete link.  I need to get the userid from the row to put in the edit link like [Edit](/edit/27).  Everything works, but I cannot figure out how to get the userid number.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#table-list-users tr td#dropmenu").hover(function(){

    // get the value of the row id.  This will be used in the edit href later on
    var data = $(this).parent('td#userid').text();
    console.log(data);

    $(this).append('<div> <a href="/edit/data <-that will be the id">edit</a> | view | delete </div>') }, function(){
        $(this).children("div").remove();
    })
});
```

Comment: For starters you can't repeat ID's in a page. They are unique by definition

Comment: You can use `<td id="id" data-user-id="<?php echo  $user->id; ?>">` to store the `id` in a data-attribute. Get it using something like `$(this).data('user-id')`

Comment: The ID's are unique.  That html/php is in a foreach loop echoing out all the records in a long list.

Comment: "_The ID's are unique_" They are not: `<td id="dropmenu">`

Comment: I tried $(this).data('user-id') idea before.  It seems that because I am already in the td#dropmenu, $this is refering to that <td>.  It seems I have to go up a level and come down to get id but don't know how to do.

Comment: They are:   <td id="id">
    <?php echo  $user->id; ?>
 </td>  Maybe I should have used userid like  <td id="userid"> in my example

Comment: Your `$user->id`s might be unique, the values of your `id` attributes of your HTML elements are not! `id="dropmenu"` is there twice, if they are inside a loop probably even more

Comment: So how do I get the value of userid from that particular row?  The dropdown attaches itself to two first_name and last_name.  That works.  I need to get the value of userid.

Comment: if they are in a loop, even `#userid` will be duplicate. Use `class` instead of `id`. then do something like `$('#table-list-users').on('hover', 'td', function(e) {if($(this).hasClass('dropmenu)) {let userid = $(this).closest('tr').find('.userid').text(); // do whatever you want with userid here}})`

Comment: Perfect.  That works.  Thank you very much Fr0zenFyr

Comment: @spreaderman might be helpful, but why don't you get your PHP to construct the edit buttons e.g. add ` <div class="actions"> <a href="/edit/data/<?php echo $user->id;?>">edit</a> ... </div>` Then just use CSS to show and hide on hover. Note I have changed `dropmenu` to a class to avoid duplicate id's in the html, so the CSS would be something like: `.actions { display: none; }` `#table-list-users tr td.dropmenu:hover .actions { display: block; }`

Comment: Thank you Panpipes.  That is probably a thinner solution, too. Thanks. Will try that.

Comment: I am also using datatables.  I noted that while using the jquery solution, the dropdown will only appear on the first page of results.  I can see the dropdown only for results 1 to 10.  When I go to page 2, there are no dropdown menus activated when I hover over.